# Overwrite CompareController

Tags: magento, url-rewriting

I try to override the Core CompareController. Somehow i don't get it done.
I have done some research on the Magento website: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_overload_a_controller

But it did not help override the controller.

*local/WP/Compare/etc/config.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <WP_Compare>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </WP_Compare>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <rewrite>
            <WP_Compare_Catalog_Product_Compare>
                <from><![CDATA[#^/catalog/product/compare/#]]></from>
                <to>/compare/catalog/product/compare/</to>
            </WP_Compare_Catalog_Product_Compare>
        </rewrite>
    </global>
</config>
```

*local/WP/Catalog/controllers/Product/CompareController.php*

```
<?php

require_once "Mage/Catalog/controllers/Product/CompareController.php";
class WP_Compare_Catalog_Product_CompareController extends Mage_Catalog_Product_CompareController
{

    public function addAction()
    {
        echo 'Lets GO!';
    }

}

?>
```

Can someone help me with this issue?

Thank you.

Gr.
Lex

Answer (score 4):

This is the solution for my problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
       <WP_Compare>
           <version>0.1.0</version>
       </WP_Compare>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <catalog>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <WP_Compare before="Mage_Catalog">WP_Compare_Catalog</WP_Compare>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </catalog>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Comment: Working on rewriting core controller overrides into modules and this lit the module off and let me dump those evil core overrides. As an added note, here's Prattski's entries on overriding the various blocks for 1.4.x.x and later: http://prattski.com/2010/06/24/magento-overriding-core-files-blocks-models-resources-controllers/

Answer (score -1):

You may be need to do something similar to that into your etc.xml:

```
 <frontend>
  <routers>
     <customer>
        <args>
           <modules>
              <Mymodule_Customer before="Mage_Customer">Mymodule_Customer</Mymodule_Customer>
           </modules>
        </args>
     </customer>
  </routers>
</frontend>
```

Comment: You can be specific in mentioning.